# Ionic app not served. WARN: No node_modules directory found, do you need to run npm install?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic2, command-line-interface, npm-install

i am a newbie in ionic framework. I have installed `node js-v6.10.0` and `npm` version 3.10.10 and `ionic` version -2.2.1
after creating my first app when I tried serving it using ionic lab.
I get the following errors

```
$ **ionic lab**
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
WARN: No node_modules directory found, do you need to run npm install?
There was an error serving your Ionic application: Unable to run spawn command E       rror: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users\SurajLifeean\AppData\Roaming\Co       mposer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin ENOENT
```

I dont know how to deal with it. please assist

Comment: The solution is directly in the message you copy and pasted. `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

You should run:

```
npm install
```

from the command line.

It will install the dependencies in the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response :) I did as suggested by you. but a new problem arose

Comment: Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************
There was an error serving your Ionic application: Unable to run spawn command Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Users\SurajLifeean\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin ENOENT

as prompted i did npm install -g cordova.. but still the problem persists  :(